# large DB site, need help speeding up query

Tags: sql

There has to be a faster way to get results. This works great in my small DB, but in my large scare one(20 million rows), this process takes forever. I have tried creating an index for both the lat and lon columns, but that did help. Besides hardware upgrades, is there a way I can speed this up?? currently it is taking a set of cord's and comparing them vs every row in the DB. I am limiting the results to 10.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT lat, lon, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos(    radians( lon ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM $tbl_name HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT $start, $limit",

     mysql_real_escape_string($lat),

     mysql_real_escape_string($lon),

     mysql_real_escape_string($lat),

     mysql_real_escape_string($radius));

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo oresults....

}
```

thanks,
Brian

Comment: If you use this SQL in a Program, you should pull the data to your ram and do the calculations in your program.

Comment: It's being used on a website. I know the server has memcached on it, not idea how to set it up with the DB. But I guess something for me to look into.

Comment: What SQL product is this?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark but perhaps you reduce the number of calculations by limiting the range of data to only latitudes and longitudes that could possibly be in the distance circle.

Something like:

```
$MinLatitude = $User_Latitude - $Distance
$MaxLatitude = $User_Latitude + $Distance
$MinLongitude = $User_Longitude - $Distance
$MaxLongitude = $User_Longitude + $Distance
```

Then you can add a WHERE clause to your SQL statement to reduce the number of calculations:

```
WHERE $MinLatitude <= lat AND lat <= $MaxLatitude
    AND $MinLongitude <= lon AND lon <= $MaxLongitude
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is cerate a trig table

```
Create table TrigVals (
   Radians decimal(18,15) primary Key Not null,
   Sin decimal(18,17) not null,
   Cos decimal(18,17) not null)
```

then create two additional unique indices on the sin and cos columns for reverse lookups (arcSin and arcos functions),

Populate this table for the range of values you need (latitudes, 0 to pi/2;   longitudes, 0 to pi)

And then join to these tables in your query instead of performing actual mathematical trig functions on each row you retrieve from the database.

Comment: So I'm not that good with SQL yet. But will this work if the range of values I am using to compare against the DB is always changing? If you don't mind going into a little further detail or possibly a link, that would be great.